# Changing tags on an npm package: Registry returned 400 for PUT on https://registry.npmjs.com/-/package/path-protocol-test/dist-tags/latest

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to promote the package with tag “dev” to “latest” by running:

`npm dist-tag add --registry https://registry.npmjs.com/ "path-protocol-test@dev" "latest"`

I get `Registry returned 400 for PUT on https://registry.npmjs.com/-/package/path-protocol-test/dist-tags/latest`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What if you try with specific version e.g. `npm dist-tag add path-protocol-test@0.0.4 latest` ?

Comment: @Teneff - that works. But with the internal Frog Artifactory registry that we use at work, I am able to switch tags, like I tried in the question. It looks like some functionality discrepancy between that and npmjs.org